# Cant connect oracle db on windows 7

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I install oracle 11g   Release 2 on windows 7.

So, installation was completed successfully, but when I am trying to connect oracle using sqlplus, I got error: `invalid username/password`

As username, I use my windows username (this user has administrator privileges).

As password I use that password, which I type during oracle intalation, but anyway I got that error.

Can you tell please what may be problem? Thanks

Comment: Your Windows username is not the username you need for your database. Not sure about Oracle, but try `root`, with the password you used at installation.

Comment: No, using `root`  as username not solves my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to connect as a admin:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Comment: When I trying this, I got message: `insufficient privileges`

Comment: sqlplus system/your_pass as sysdba